# Issue in Pure CSS3 LavaLamp Tab menu Hover

Tags: html, css

I implemented the Lavalamp tab menu in my website: when Mouse goes on absolute Div "#lavalamp" bottom "subs" div not display.How to fixed this, please help me.

[Detail code click here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lmgkhxd/)

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Magento</a>
    <div class="subs colbg01">
        Submenu 1
    </div>
</li>

<li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Wordpress</a>
    <div class="subs colbg02">
        Submenu 2
    </div>
</li>

<li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Mobile App</a>
    <div class="subs colbg03">
        Submenu 3
    </div>    
</li>
<div id="lavalamp"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No quite sure I fully understand your problem. Could you perhaps explain a little more what it is that is not happening and what it is that you want to happen?

Comment: @lee_gladding :: Check my Edit question i upload 2 screen shots on that

Comment: I think it's the little triangle dowsn't stay the same color as the sub menu on tabs 2 and 3 but works on tab 1, have a look at detail code

Comment: when you hover on body, not menu.....

Comment: arrow move on triangle then below div background color missed

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens when you hover over the triangle, which causes the underlining `li` to lose its own hover and thus invalidating the active `li:nth-child(..) ~ #lavalamp` rule.

You can solve this issue with modern browsers by disabling the pointer events on the lavalamp element

```
#lavalamp{pointer-events:none;}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6Lmgkhxd/4/

---

***Notice***: IE added support for `pointer-events` on v11

Comment: @RaviGadhiya only through javascript.

Comment: there is another workaround but it working depends on how the rest of your page is set up. It is the `z-index` solution suggested by @lee_gladding. But it depends on the `li` elements being transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because the hover state of the li is being broken when hovering over the `#lavalamp` element (which appears later in the DOM).

If you really want a CSS only fix you can use `z-index` to place the triangle behind everything else and bring the li forward.

like:

```
#nav li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 20px 18px 20px;
    z-index: 1; // <--- added this
}

#lavalamp {
    z-index: -1; // add this
    ... other code
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lmgkhxd/3/

I changed the li's background-color to transparent to allow this to work.

Also there seems to be a slight gap between the li and the`.subs` so I increased the bottom padding of the li to overlap better to the 50px top positioned `.subs` (from `16px` to `18px`)

Comment: In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index can be tricky in older IE browsers. But the suggested way in order to correct this is to give the parent a higher z-index that the positioned child. So as long as the `.nav` / `ul` has a higher z-index than the `#lavalamp` AND the `li`'s do too, this should work as far as I can tell in IE9 yeah. Not got chance to test just yet I am afraid but perhaps later I can. But let me know if you have already tried and it does not work.